# How to automatically include a concern in all Active Admin Page controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, activesupport-concern, ruby-module

I have the following concern:

*./app/controllers/concerns/activity_helper.rb*

```rb
module ActivityHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :my_method, except: %i[update destroy]
  end

  def my_method
    ...
  end
end
```

Currently i am including this concern in several Active Admin page controllers manually like so:

*./app/admin/dashboard.rb*

```rb
controller do
  include ActivityHelper
end
```

I already tried the following but it **does not work without giving any error**:

1. I created a new module in *./app/controllers/concerns/active_admin_controller_concern.rb*:

```rb
module ActiveAdminControllerConcern
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
       controller do
          include ActivityHelper
       end
   end
end
```

2. I added the following method and config in *./config/initializers/active_admin.rb*:

```rb
def add_active_admin_controller_concern
  ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL.send(:include, ActiveAdminControllerConcern)
end
```

```rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.before_action :add_active_admin_controller_concern
end
```

How to automatically include only the module ActivityHelper in all Active Admin page controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the file *./app/controllers/concerns/active_admin_controller_concern.rb*

Just add the following line at the end of the file *./config/initializers/active_admin.rb*

```rb
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_admin_controller) do
  include ActivityHelper
end
```